# Neo4j count max concurrent sessions

Tags: neo4j

Each session has a start_time and an end_time.

Within some period of time, I want to know what was the maximum number of concurrent sessions.

```
MATCH (s:SESSION)
WHERE s.start_time > #{window_start_time}
  AND s.end_time < #{window_end_time}
RETURN s
ORDER BY s.start_time
```

With these nodes sorted by start_time, we can count the number of sessions going on at that time

```
MATCH (s:SESSION)
WHERE s.start_time < #{time}
  AND s.end_time > #{time}
RETURN count(s)
```

I'm not sure how to bring these two queries together though.

---

EDIT:

So the windowing one is simple, but it doesn't actually give the concurrent session, just the total number of sessions in that window. Michael was on the right track with start_times as critical points, but his query returns a number for every point, and I want to quantize them into windows, haha. Its complicated -- I'm really close though!

```
WITH 1441177372629/1000 AS begin, 
     1441582329570/1000 AS end,
    1000*60*60/1000 as step
WITH begin, end, step
MATCH (s:SESSION)
WHERE s.start_time/1000 > begin AND s.end_time/1000 < end
WITH step,
     collect(s) as sessions,
     range(begin, end, step) AS times,
     collect(DISTINCT s.start_time/1000) AS slots
UNWIND times AS time
WITH step, time, sessions, 
     filter(slot in slots WHERE slot > time AND slot <= time+step) AS timeSlots
WITH time, sessions, reduce(count = 0, slot IN timeSlots |
  size(filter(s IN sessions WHERE s.start_time/1000 <= slot AND s.end_time/1000 >= slot))
) AS counts
RETURN time, counts
ORDER BY time
```

Here are my problems:

1) timestamps (ms since epoc) overflow a 32 bit int! I kept getting a negative range and thats why. Its pretty annoying -- I have to divide by 1000 in a bunch of places. Maybe theres a better way?

2) my reduce isnt correct. I want to take the max of the number of concurrent sessions in that window, but I can't do this:

```
max(count, size(filter(s IN sessions WHERE s.start_time/1000 <= slot AND s.end_time/1000 >= slot)))
```

It seems I cant use WITH or CASE inside that resduce function so I dont know what to do...

Comment: Not really sure I can follow. Where does your `time` come from?

Comment: and use parameters not string substitutions !!!

Answer (score 2):

This should work, you need a kind of window function which we can simulate by aggregating the distinct start-times to get our slots.

And then for each of the start-times filter all sessions to the ones that are running during that time.

```
MATCH (s:Session)
WHERE s.start_time > 12345000 AND s.end_time < 12348000
WITH collect(s) AS sessions, collect(DISTINCT s.start_time) AS slots UNWIND slots AS slot
RETURN slot, size(filter(s IN sessions 
                         WHERE s.start_time <= slot AND s.end_time >= slot)) AS sessions
ORDER BY slot;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to concatenate both queries you can use *with*:

```
MATCH (s:SESSION)
WHERE s.start_time > #{window_start_time}
AND s.end_time < #{window_end_time}
WITH s
ORDER BY s.start_time   
WHERE s.start_time < #{time}
AND s.end_time > #{time}
RETURN count(s)
```

Now the results of the first statement are used for the second one.
More information about *WITH* can be found on the official documentation: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html

Comment: `#{time}` needs to be the start time for each session though. Thus calculating the max concurrent sessions

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start with your time window and count the concurrent sessions from there :

Test console : http://console.neo4j.org/r/11hw2x

example query :

```
UNWIND range(12345000, 12348000) AS window
MATCH (n:Session)
WHERE n.start_time < window AND n.end_time > window
RETURN window, count(*);
```

Which will return such result :

```
12346647    100
12346961    100
12345588    64
12346306    100
12345561    61
12345247    25
12345902    86
```